# How to simulate a queue and a stack JavaFX with pause, threads(task, service)

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I been searching in YouTube, Stack-Overflow and fxexperience, even oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) but I still don't get it. 
There's not similar example :(

The problem is how to do a stack and queue simulator.

1. Generate 10 random numbers. Done.
2. Show the numbers in a table. Done.
3. Use the 10 random numbers to simulate a stack and a queue. I don't now how to comunicate the service with the TextField.
4. Pause the simulation. or Stop.

-The program needs a pause method. I don't know how to pause a thead. Perhaps with wait() and notify(). I don't know.

I have used label.textProperty.bind(service.progressProperty()). this works but when i try to bind a variable instead 
the method updateProgress(i,n) throws a exception.

Maybe I need to use 2 Tasks.

Main class:

```
package simulation;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/simulation/simulation.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX and concurrency, Stack and Queue");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Controller Class:

```
package simulation;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class SimulationCt implements Initializable {

  @FXML private TableView table;
  @FXML private TableColumn i_tc;
  @FXML private TableColumn random_tc;

  @FXML private TextField stack_start;
  @FXML private TextField stack_1;
  @FXML private TextField stack_2;
  @FXML private TextField stack_3;
  @FXML private TextField stack_4;
  @FXML private TextField stack_5;
  @FXML private TextField stack_final;

  @FXML private TextField queue_start;
  @FXML private TextField queue_1;
  @FXML private TextField queue_2;
  @FXML private TextField queue_3;
  @FXML private TextField queue_4;
  @FXML private TextField queue_5;
  @FXML private TextField queue_final;

  @FXML private Button new_b;
  @FXML private Button play_pause_b;
  @FXML private Button stop_b;

  @FXML private ProgressBar progress_bar;

  private ObservableList<RandomNumber> numberList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

  private CalculateService backProcess;

  @FXML
  private void createNew () {
    disableNew(true);
    generateRandom();
    backProcess = new CalculateService();
    progress_bar.progressProperty().bind(backProcess.progressProperty());
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
      backProcess.start();
    });
  }

  @FXML
  private void playPause () {
    if(backProcess.getState().equals(Worker.State.RUNNING)) {
      System.out.println("stoping...");
      backProcess.cancel();
    } else if (backProcess.getState().equals(Worker.State.CANCELLED)) {
      System.out.println("restarting...");
      backProcess.restart();
    }
  }

  @FXML
  private void stop () {
    if(backProcess.getState().equals(Worker.State.RUNNING)) {
      System.out.println("stoping...");
      backProcess.cancel();
    } else if (backProcess.getState().equals(Worker.State.CANCELLED)) {
      System.out.println("already stoped...");
    }
    clearItems();
    disableNew(false);
  }

  // cleans the list and the progress bar.
  private void clearItems () {
    progress_bar.progressProperty().unbind();
    progress_bar.progressProperty().set(0.0);
    numberList.clear();
  }

  private void disableNew (boolean b) {
    new_b.setDisable(b);
    play_pause_b.setDisable(!b);
    stop_b.setDisable(!b);
  }

  // generates random numbers to fill the table, these numbers are the ones for the stack and the queue.
  private void generateRandom () {
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
      int rnd = (int)(Math.random() * (200 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
      numberList.add(new RandomNumber(i, rnd ));
    }
  }

  private void startTable () {
    i_tc.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory("i"));
    random_tc.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory("number"));
    table.setItems(numberList);
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    disableNew(false);
    startTable();
  }
}
```

FXML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

  <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="simulation.SimulationCt">
  <children>
        <TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="282.0" prefWidth="162.0">
          <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="i_tc" prefWidth="28.0" text="i" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="random_tc" prefWidth="122.0" text="Random Number" />
          </columns>
        </TableView>
        <GridPane layoutX="303.0">
           <columnConstraints>
              <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="false" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="50.0" />
              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
              <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="false" halignment="RIGHT" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="50.0" />
           </columnConstraints>
           <rowConstraints>
              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
           </rowConstraints>
           <children>
              <Label text="Stack" />
              <VBox GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                 <children>
                    <TextField fx:id="stack_start" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                    <Label text="new" />
                 </children>
              </VBox>
              <VBox GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                 <children>
                    <TextField fx:id="stack_1" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                    <TextField fx:id="stack_2" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                    <TextField fx:id="stack_3" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                    <TextField fx:id="stack_4" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                    <TextField fx:id="stack_5" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                 </children>
              </VBox>
              <VBox GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                 <children>
                    <TextField fx:id="stack_final" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                    <Label text="last" />
                 </children>
              </VBox>
           </children>
        </GridPane>
        <GridPane layoutX="193.0" layoutY="155.0">
           <columnConstraints>
              <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="false" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
              <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="false" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
           </columnConstraints>
           <rowConstraints>
              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
           </rowConstraints>
           <children>
              <Label text="Queue" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
              <VBox GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                 <children>
                    <TextField fx:id="queue_start" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                    <Label text="new" />
                 </children>
              </VBox>
              <HBox spacing="5.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                 <children>
                    <TextField fx:id="queue_1" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                    <TextField fx:id="queue_2" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                    <TextField fx:id="queue_3" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                    <TextField fx:id="queue_4" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                    <TextField fx:id="queue_5" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                 </children>
              </HBox>
              <VBox GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="TOP">
                 <children>
                    <TextField fx:id="queue_final" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                    <Label text="last" />
                 </children>
              </VBox>
           </children>
        </GridPane>
        <Button fx:id="new_b" onAction="#createNew" layoutX="266.0" layoutY="243.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New" />
        <Button fx:id="play_pause_b" onAction="#playPause" layoutX="326.0" layoutY="243.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Play / Pause" />
        <Button fx:id="stop_b" onAction="#stop" layoutX="428.0" layoutY="243.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stop" />
        <ProgressBar fx:id="progress_bar" layoutX="266.0" layoutY="277.0" prefWidth="200.0" progress="0.0" />
  </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

DataHelper:

```
package simulation;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;

public class RandomNumber {

  private IntegerProperty i;
  private IntegerProperty number;

  public RandomNumber(int i, int number) {
    this.i = new SimpleIntegerProperty(i);
    this.number = new SimpleIntegerProperty(number);
  }

  public int getI() {
    return i.get();
  }

  public IntegerProperty iProperty() {
    return i;
  }

  public void setI(int i) {
    this.i.set(i);
  }

  public int getNumber() {
    return number.get();
  }

  public IntegerProperty numberProperty() {
    return number;
  }

  public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number.set(number);
  }

}
```

Service class:

```
package simulation;

import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class CalculateService extends Service {
  int n = 20; // this does the trick to simulate the pause.
  int j = 0; // even if the task is canceled the last value is saved here.

  @Override
  protected Task createTask() {
    return new Task() {
      @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {
        int a;
        int b;
        int iterations;
        for (iterations = j; iterations <= n; iterations++) {
          j = iterations;
          if (isCancelled()) {
            updateMessage("Cancelled");
            break;
          }
          updateProgress(iterations, n);
          System.out.println("number: " + j);

          //Block the thread for a short time, but be sure
          //to check the InterruptedException for cancellation
          try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
          } catch (InterruptedException interrupted) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
              updateMessage("Cancelled");
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        return null;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of code in the question, and I don't think you need it all to address the concepts you're actually asking about. So I'll just give a high-level answer here. If you want to edit your question to something much simpler that addresses the actual issue, then I can make this specific to that example.

I would probably try to do this without threads at all, but using the animation API. For example, you could use a `Timeline`, with the following basic outline:

```
public class Controller {

    // @FXML-annotated UI elements...
    // Other state....

    private Timeline timeline ;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(100)), e -> {
            if (moreStepsToDo()) {
                doNextStep();
            } else {
                stopSimulation();
            }
        });
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    }

    private boolean moreStepsToDo() {
        // return true if there are more steps in the simulation,
        // false otherwise
    }

    private void doNextStep() {
        // do next step in the simulation
    }

    @FXML
    private void stopSimulation() {
        timeline.stop();
    }

    @FXML
    private void pauseSimulation() {
        timeline.pause();
    }

    @FXML
    private void playSimulation() {
        timeline.play();
    }

    @FXML
    private void resetSimulation() {
        timeline.jumpTo(Duration.ZERO);
    }
}
```

The nice thing about this solution is that everything is single-threaded: the event handler for the key frame is executed on the FX Application Thread, which is the same thread that executes the event handlers. This means there is no need to worry about synchronizing data across threads. The predefined methods in the animation API `pause()`, `play()`, and `stop()` provide exactly the functionality you're looking for; you just have to update the application state appropriately.

Here's a simple complete example that uses this approach (it just moves a bunch of rectangles, one at a time, from one vbox to another).

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SimplePausableAnimation extends Application {

    private VBox left;
    private VBox right;
    private Timeline timeline;
    private Button pausePlay;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        left = new VBox(10);
        left.setMinWidth(200);
        right = new VBox(10);
        right.setMinWidth(200);

        HBox hbox = new HBox(10, left, right);

        pausePlay = new Button();

        Button reset = new Button("Reset");
        reset.setOnAction(e -> reset());

        reset();

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(hbox);

        HBox buttons = new HBox(5, pausePlay, reset);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        root.setBottom(buttons);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private void reset() {

        if (timeline != null) {
            timeline.stop();
        }

        left.getChildren().clear();
        right.getChildren().clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            left.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE));
        }

        timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> {
            if (moreStepsToDo()) {
                doNextStep();
            } else {
                timeline.stop();
            }
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        pausePlay.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
            if (left.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }, left.getChildren()));

        pausePlay.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            if (timeline.getStatus() == Animation.Status.RUNNING) {
                return "Pause";
            }
            return "Play";
        }, timeline.statusProperty()));

        pausePlay.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (timeline.getStatus() == Animation.Status.RUNNING) {
                timeline.pause();
            } else {
                timeline.play();
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean moreStepsToDo() {
        return !left.getChildren().isEmpty();
    }

    private void doNextStep() {
        int n = left.getChildren().size();
        Node node = left.getChildren().remove(n - 1);
        right.getChildren().add(node);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you do want to do this with threads, one approach to pausing a thread is to use a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) with a single permit. This generally looks something like this:

```
Semaphore pauser = new Semaphore(1);

Thread simulationThread = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        while (! Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            pauser.acquire();
            // do simulation step
            pauser.release();
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
        // ignore and exit thread...
    }
});
```

(Obviously the same idiom will work in your `Task`, which is executed on a background thread.)

Then calling `pauser.acquire();` from the controller will pause the simulation (because the simulation thread will not be able to acquire the permit), and calling `pauser.release()` while it is paused will let it run again.