# How to stack shapes in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, stack

I want to implement a stack using JavaFX and I have already got most things working out. The only problem is I want to display the value of the stack inside a rectangle and stack each rectangle with its corresponding value one on the other but I don't have any idea on how to do so.
Here is my code so far

```
import DataStructuresImp.Stack;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StudyJavaFx extends Application {
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
    private double vGap = 50;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(25,30,60,30);
        rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        Button insert = new Button("Insert");
        Button delete = new Button("Delete");
        java.util.ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(insert,delete,textField);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(pane);
        borderPane.setBottom(hBox);
        borderPane.setTop(vBox);

        BorderPane.setAlignment(hBox,Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane,500,500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("value in rectangle");
        primaryStage.show();


        insert.setOnAction(e-> {
            String value = textField.getText();
            int x = 180;
            int y = 475;

                if (isBlank(value)) {
                    vBox.getChildren().clear();
                    vBox.getChildren().add(new Text(20, 20, "Please Enter value!"));
                } else {
                    if (!stack.inside(value)) {
                        stack.push(value);
                        vBox.getChildren().clear();
                        for (int i =1;i<stack.size();i++){
                            displayStack(x, y*i, vGap);
                        }

                        System.out.println(stack);

                    } else {
                        vBox.getChildren().clear();
                        vBox.getChildren().add(new Text(20, 20, "Value is already present in stack!"));
                    }
                    if (stack.isEmpty())
                        return;
                }
        });
    }

    public void displayStack(){
            displayStack(180,475,vGap);

    }

    public void displayStack( double x, double y, double vGap){
       Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(x ,y - vGap ,150,20);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(rectangle, new Text(x+65,y-35,stack.peek()));
    }

    public Boolean isBlank(String value){
      if (value!=null && !value.isEmpty() && !value.trim().isEmpty()){
          return false;
      } else return true;
    }

    /*public static void main(String[]args){
        StudyJavaFx object = new StudyJavaFx();
        System.out.println(object.isBlank("  "));
    }*/


}
```

Here is my stack class

```
package DataStructuresImp;

public class Stack<E> {
    private java.util.ArrayList<E> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    public void push(E e){
        list.add(e);
    }

    public E pop(){
        if (list.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }
        E top = list.get(list.size() - 1);
        list.remove(list.size()- 1);
        return top;
    }

    public E peek(){
        if (list.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }
        E top  = list.get(list.size()-1);
        return top;
    }

    public boolean inside(E value){
        return list.contains(value);
    }

    public int size(){
        return list.size();
    }


    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return list.isEmpty();
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Stack: " + list.toString();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stack<Integer> list = new Stack<>();

        list.push(5);
        list.push(7);
        list.push(4);
        list.push(9);

        for (int i = 0; i<list.size();i++)
        System.out.println(list);

        System.out.println("Is stack empty: " + list.isEmpty());


        System.out.println("Stack size " +list.size());
        list.pop();
        list.pop();
        System.out.println("is Stack empty: " + list.isEmpty());
        System.out.println(list.size());
        System.out.println("After pop" +list);


    }

}
```

Comment: See also [_How to simulate a queue and a stack JavaFX…_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49390022/230513).

Comment: First, your loop starts counting at 1, instead of 0.  Second, you increment the y-coordinate by 475 for each element of the stack, which is way too much (if you expand the window enough, you might see two elements). And third, you call `peek()` each time, so each time you see the top element of the stack (so you display the same element each time). The typical interface to a stack doesn't allow you to see anything except the current top element; if your UI want to display all elements, it either needs to empty the stack, or have "privileged" access to the entire underlying list.